# Document_Open() does not work in other files

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a VBA project containing 1 module (m1) and 1 userform (uf).
In "ThisDocument" I am calling a public sub from "m1" that initializes a collection I then refer to in the userform. This works perfectly fine until I deploy this project to other files.

I save the file as a .dotm in the %Appdata%/Microsoft/word/startup folder so I can use the project in all of my word files. But as soon as I try to use my project in other files the userform opens itself as designed but the collection is empty.

What could be the problem here?

Manually calling the initialization method from the userform works fine.

```
'----------------------------------------------ThisDocument
Private Sub Document_Open()
    initBetaCollection
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------m1
Option Explicit

Public beta As Collection

Sub initBetaCollection()

    Set beta = New Collection

    beta.Add Array("0041", "A"), Key:="0041"
    '...

End Sub

'----------------------------------------------uf
Option Explicit
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim search As String

    'Defining the textinput as "search"
    search = txtSearch.Value

    For Each arr In beta
        If search <> "" Then 'No empty search field
            If arr(1) Like "*" & search & "*" Then 'Match found
                lbResults.AddItem arr(0)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I get the: Run Time Error '424' object required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using `Document_Open` in the `ThisDocument` class or a macro named `AutoOpen` in a regular module is that both execute specifically for this document (or documents created from the template), *only*.

In order to have an application-level event, that fires for all documents opened, it's necessary to work with application-level events.

For this, first a **class module** is required. In the class module, the following code is needed:

```
'Class module named: Class1
Public WithEvents app As Word.Application

Private Sub app_DocumentOpen(ByVal Doc As Document)
    'MsgBox Doc.FullName & ": on Open"
    'Code here that should fire when a document is opened
    'If something needs to be done with this document, use 
    'the Doc parameter passed to the event, don't try to use ActiveDocument
End Sub
```

Then, in a regular module, an `AutoExec` macro can be used to initialize the class with event handling. (`AutoExec`: fires when Word starts and loads a template with a macro of this name.)

```
Option Explicit

Dim theApp As New Class1

Sub AutoExec()
    'MsgBox "AutoExec"
    Set theApp.app = Word.Application        
End Sub

'Sub AutoOpen()
'    MsgBox "Open in AutoOpen" - fires only for this document
'End Sub
```

Comment: @schefflaa  Because it's commented out? I did test this quite thoroughly (and it's still working today because I forgot to "turn it off"). The template with the code needs to be in the Startup folder. Code should not be commented out. `Document_Open` will only fire when another document is *opened*, not when a new one is created. Make sure `Document_Open` is in a *class* module and that the class module name matches what's in the `Dim theApp As...` line in the "plain" module.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that it worked on existing files so I just added the app_NewDocument method and it worked perfectly fine. Yet my form that normally responds to the ctrl+space shortcut does not seem to work properly with this. I had this piece of code in my m1 module: [link](https://imgur.com/G8e7Keh)

Comment: I get the _Run-time error 5346 Word cannot change the function..._ when I try to call it from the `Document_Open` method

Comment: @schefflaa For the *new issues* you bring up in comments I recommend you post a new question *for each issue*. Be sure to include all relevant information for reproducing *in the question, itself*. Don't try to link to outside files - this is a security risk for others and the information will probably not be available at a later date for others seeking help. Stack Overflow is not a "forum", but a Q&A repository. (You may want to review the information in the [help].)